# ABAP CALL TRANSACTION and fill variant field

Tags: abap

I used this bit of code the exact same way in a previous program and it worked. Now I am using it to apply to a transaction with a range available for the field I want to fill with the information clicked on the hotspot. It is not placing anything in the field when taken to ME2N view. Any suggestions?

```
FORM user_command USING r_ucomm LIKE sy-ucomm 
rs_selfield TYPE slis_selfield.

 CASE r_ucomm.
 WHEN '&IC1'.                                     

  IF rs_selfield-fieldname = 'EBELN'.
   READ TABLE itab_usr INTO wa_usr INDEX rs_selfield-tabindex.  
   SET PARAMETER ID 'BES' FIELD wa_usr-ebeln.

   CALL TRANSACTION 'ME2N'.

  ENDIF.
 ENDCASE.
ENDFORM.
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is basically writing something on the wall and then nudging the next person. It's up to the next person to decide whether they want to read whatever's written on the wall. The parameters area is just a global memory - perhaps the called program will do something about it, but unless it states so in its documentation, you can't rely on that.

In the case of `ME2N`, you may want to examine the transaction and find out that it simply calls the selection screen of a report, let's say `RM06EN00`. You may then want to look up the keyword `SUBMIT` and the relevant documentation about [filling the selection screen of a called program](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_470/helpdata/en/9f/dba51a35c111d1829f0000e829fbfe/content.htm).

Answer (score 0):

You can find more information from [here](https://onryzc.com/2018/10/26/1426/).

```
DATA : WA_FCAT             TYPE LVC_S_FCAT,
       IT_FCAT             TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF LVC_S_FCAT,
       OB_CUSTOM_CONTAINER TYPE REF TO CL_GUI_CUSTOM_CONTAINER,
       OB_GRID             TYPE REF TO CL_GUI_ALV_GRID,
       G_VARIANT           LIKE DISVARIANT,
       LT_DEMO_DATA        TYPE TABLE OF ZDEMO_TABLE.

INITIALIZATION.

START-OF-SELECTION.

  " GET DATA .
  REFRESH LT_DEMO_DATA.
  SELECT * INTO TABLE LT_DEMO_DATA FROM ZDEMO_TABLE.

  PERFORM FIELDCAT.

  CALL SCREEN 1001.

CLASS LCL_EVENT_HANDLER DEFINITION.
  PUBLIC SECTION.
    METHODS HANDLE_HOTSPOT_CLICK FOR EVENT HOTSPOT_CLICK OF CL_GUI_ALV_GRID
      IMPORTING E_ROW_ID E_COLUMN_ID ES_ROW_NO.
ENDCLASS.

CLASS LCL_EVENT_HANDLER IMPLEMENTATION.
  METHOD HANDLE_HOTSPOT_CLICK .
    PERFORM HOTSPOT_CLICK USING E_ROW_ID E_COLUMN_ID.
  ENDMETHOD.
ENDCLASS.

FORM HOTSPOT_CLICK USING E_ROW TYPE LVC_S_ROW E_COLUMN_ID TYPE  LVC_S_COL.

  DATA : WA_DEMO TYPE ZDEMO_TABLE.
  READ TABLE LT_DEMO_DATA  INTO WA_DEMO INDEX E_ROW-INDEX.

  SET PARAMETER ID 'MAT' FIELD WA_DEMO-MATNR.
  CALL TRANSACTION 'MB51'.

ENDFORM.

*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*&      Module  STATUS_1001  OUTPUT
*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*
MODULE STATUS_1001 OUTPUT.
  SET PF-STATUS 'STANDARD_FULLSCREEN'.
  SET TITLEBAR 'TITLE'.

  IF G_VARIANT IS INITIAL.
    G_VARIANT-REPORT   = SY-REPID.
    G_VARIANT-USERNAME = SY-UNAME.
  ENDIF.


  "Object creation for custom container exporting the name
  CREATE OBJECT OB_CUSTOM_CONTAINER
    EXPORTING
      CONTAINER_NAME = 'ALV_GRID'.

  CREATE OBJECT OB_GRID
    EXPORTING
      I_PARENT = OB_CUSTOM_CONTAINER.

  CALL METHOD OB_GRID->SET_TABLE_FOR_FIRST_DISPLAY
    EXPORTING
      IS_VARIANT      = G_VARIANT
      I_DEFAULT       = 'X'
      I_SAVE          = 'A'
    CHANGING
      IT_FIELDCATALOG = IT_FCAT
      IT_OUTTAB       = LT_DEMO_DATA.

**** For Hotspot Event Handling
  DATA: G_HANDLER TYPE REF TO LCL_EVENT_HANDLER.
  CREATE OBJECT G_HANDLER.
  SET HANDLER G_HANDLER->HANDLE_HOTSPOT_CLICK FOR OB_GRID.
ENDMODULE.
*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*&      Form  FIELDCAT
*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*


ENDFORM.
*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*&      Module  USER_COMMAND_1001  INPUT
*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*
MODULE USER_COMMAND_1001 INPUT.
  IF   SY-UCOMM = '&F03' OR SY-UCOMM = '&F12' OR SY-UCOMM = '&F15'.

    FREE: OB_GRID.
    REFRESH: LT_DEMO_DATA.
    LEAVE TO SCREEN 0.
  ENDIF.
ENDMODULE.
```